# The fastest way to write data while producing it

Tags: c++, optimization, file-io, parallel-processing

In my program I am simulating a N-body system for a large number of iterations. For each iteration I produce a set of 6N coordinates which I need to append to a file and then use for executing the next iteration. The code is written in C++ and currently makes use of `ofstream`'s method `write()` to write the data in binary format at each iteration.

I am not an expert in this field, but I would like to improve this part of the program, since I am in the process of optimizing the whole code. I feel that the latency associated with writing the result of the computation at each cycle significantly slows down the performance of the software.

I'm confused because I have no experience in actual parallel programming and low level file I/O. I thought of some abstract techniques that I imagined I could implement, since I am programming for modern (possibly multi-core) machines with Unix OSes:

- Writing the data in the file in chunks of n iterations (there seem to be better ways to proceed...)
- Parallelizing the code with OpenMP (how to actually implement a buffer so that the threads are synchronized appropriately, and do not overlap?)
- Using `mmap` (the file size could be huge, on the order of GBs, is this approach robust enough?)

However, I don't know how to best implement them and combine them appropriately.

Comment: "I feel that the latency associated with writing the result of the computation at each cycle significantly slows down the performance of the software." do you feel it or you profiled your code?

Comment: Have you profiled the code to make sure your feelings about the latency are correct?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What could be the fastest techniques for writing the data and doing the computation at the same time and how to implement them. I know it is a very basic question, but I am not an expert in implementing even simple optimizations, such as a buffer. So I would like to know what APIs and techniques I should study

Comment: If you want intelligent suggestions you need to give some numbers.

Comment: N-Body problems require, in general, O(n^2) operations for each iteration.  Writing your data requires O(n) operations.  Assuming your program conforms to those generalities, you''ll find optimizing each iteration will yield better results than trying to optimize the output.  Of course you shouldn't take my word on any of this until you have, as Alessandro suggests, completely profiled your program to see where the bottlenecks exist.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi,Grizzly I have not profiled the code, but I can intermingle computations without writing their result in the disk. When I add them the software does not slow down significantly. In my opinion this means that the disk I/O is slow compared to the computation

Comment: @andand (wow.. I am impressed by the quantity and the quality of the responses). What I am now trying to do is to maximize the number of iterations, not the number of bodies, so the "coefficient of the n" in the O(n) part is high. Anyway thanks to all for pointing out the need to profile the code (I'm now figuring out how to do, I am a beginner..) and thanks to you for your observation

Comment: It's not a very specific question.

Comment: @andand: "O(n^2)...you''ll find optimizing each iteration will yield better results than trying to optimize the output". You're assuming that he isn't using Ewald summation or the Fast Multipole Method, that the constant prefactor for disk IO is insignificant and that *n* is large. I doubt any of those assumptions are true. The question states that the number of iterations is large, not the number of bodies. Disk IO is orders of magnitude slower than arithmetic on CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course writing into a file at each iteration is inefficient and most likely slow down your computing. (as a rule of thumb, depends on your actuel case)

You have to use a [*producer* -> *consumer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) design pattern. They will be linked by a queue, like a conveyor belt.

- The producer will try to produce as fast as it can, only slowing if the consumer can't handle it.
- The consumer will try to "consume" as fast as it can.

By splitting the two, you can increase performance more easily because each process is simpler and has less interferences from the other.

- If the producer is faster, you need to improve the consumer, in your case by writing into file in the most efficient way, chunk by chunk most likely (as you said)
- If the consumer is faster, you need to improve the producer, most likely by parallelizing it as you said.

There is **no need** to optimize both. Only optimize the slowest (the bottleneck).

Practically, you use threads and a synchronized queue between them. For implementation hints, have a look [here](http://www.quantnet.com/cplusplus-multithreading-boost/), especially §18.12 "The Producer-Consumer Pattern".

About flow management, you'll have to add a little bit more complexity by selecting a "max queue size" and making the producer(s) wait if the queue has not enough space. Beware of deadlocks then, code it carefully. (see the wikipedia link I gave about that)

Note : It's a good idea to use boost threads because threads are not very portable. (well, they are since C++0x but C++0x availability is not yet good)

Comment: But, given the size of the data, how to handle the case where the producer is so fast that it produces something that cannot be stored in memory before the consumer manages to save it to the disk?

Comment: @Fiat Lux Well if you produce data faster than can be stored on your filesystem you have a pretty basic problem completely independent of any software tricks you do. If your bandwidth is too small, sooner or later you'll run out of buffer space and then you'll have to handle that case anyhow.

Comment: @FiatLux that's why I said "procducer...only slowing if the consumer can't handle it". I edited to add a link to an implementation example + suggested improvements. You'll have to make the producers wait if memory is full.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to split operation into two independent processes: `data-producing` and `file-writing`. `Data-producing` would use some buffer for iteration-wise data passing, and `file-writing` would use a queue to store write requests. Then, `data-producing` would just post a write request and go on, while `file-writing` would cope with the writing in the background.

Essentially, if the data is produced much faster than it can possibly be stored, you'll quickly end up holding most of it in the buffer. In that case your actual approach seems to be quite reasonable as is, since little can be done programmatically then to improve the situation.

Comment: Why do you think you can do a better job of buffering than the OS block cache already does?

Comment: @SteveC Because it's generally better to implement the algorithm in the deterministic way, than rely upon implementation-dependent features. I mean, block cache *is* good, but it might or might not fit the specific situation. It might not be as portable, it might not be as fast, etc., and the OP wasn't too specific anyway :)

Comment: In that case you should not go through two layers of buffering, but just bypass the filesystem and write to the raw disk.  That's "more deterministic" and you can "make it fit the specific situation".  Personally, I doubt you can do a better job than the filesystem authors.

Comment: @SteveC: I wouldn't even try to, but you've missed the point. Which is: versatile program languages are agnostic to any undelying OS support (and C++ is). OS buffering may be switched off or completely absent for many reasons, and we can't rely on it unless its presence is explicitly required or guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to play with doing stuff in a different threads, you could try using [aio_write()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/aio_write), which allows asynchronous writes. Essentially you give the OS the buffer to write, and the function returns immediately, and finishes the the write while your program continues, you can check later to see if the write has completed.

This solution still does suffer from the producer/consumer problem mentioned in other answers, if your algorithm is producing data faster than it can be written, eventually you will run out of memory to store the results between the algorithm and the write, so you'd have to try it and see how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

> "Using mmap (the file size could be huge, on the order of GBs, is this
>   approach robust enough?)"

mmap is the OS's method of loading programs, shared libraries and the page/swap file - it's as robust as any other file I/O and generally higher performance.

BUT on most OS's it's bad/difficult/impossible to expand the size of a mapped file while it's being used. So if you know the size of the data, or you are only reading, it's great. For a log/dump that you are continually adding to it's less sutiable - unless you know some maximum size.

Comment: I know the size of the data, but there will be no problem with 32 bit systems if I have a file of some gigabytes?

Comment: @Fiat - that's the big advantage of mmap. You can map multiple views into the file with offsets so you can use a window to access any part of a file as big as your FS will allow. The details depend on your OS